# Set taskbar icon of top level usercontrol (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, taskbar

I have a top level (ie. acts like a window) `UserControl` (.NET 4.0) which I am using to simulate a custom form. I can easily set the title text and taskbar text like so:

```
public override string Text
{
    get { return base.Text; }
    set
    {
        base.Text = value
        TitleText.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Which sets both the title text and taskbar text:

[image: What I have achieved so far]

<sub>*Please note that the bar down the bottom of the image is my actual taskbar; I have installed an alternate shell*</sub>

---

The problem I have come across is that I can't seem to set the taskbar icon of this `UserControl` as it has no overridable `Icon` property so I can't set the taskbar icon as I would with the text. Please also note that the icon shown in the `UserControl` is just a `PictureBox` containing an image.


So, in short I want to be able to do this:

[image: What I want to achieve]

But I can't do this as there is no `Icon` property for a `UserControl`:

```
public override Icon Icon
{
    get { return base.Icon; }
    set
    {
         base.Icon = value;
         TitleBarIcon.Image = value.ToBitmap();
    }
}
```

---

How can I change the taskbar icon?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I got you right but I think you have to possibilites:

Either set the Icon of the ParentForm.

Or set the ApplicationIcon as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx

**EDIT:**

As you are using a control as TopLevelControl you need to send the [WM_SETICON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) during the creation of the control - as the form does!

Taken from the Form.CreateHandle:

```
        Icon icon = this.Icon;
        if (icon != null && this.TaskbarOwner.Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(this.TaskbarOwner, 128, 1, icon.Handle);
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these work. Changing the icon of the ParentForm will do nothing as the UserControl is separate from the form and has its own place in the taskbar. As for the second possibility, this will only set the icon of a form

Comment: @Levi: The second solution sets the icon which is shown in the task bar. It is recommended that you set it for all forms as well. According to MSDN: _The Icon property for a project specifies the icon file (.ico) that will be displayed for the compiled application in File Explorer and in the Windows taskbar._ and as a Note: _After you set the icon property for an application, you might also set the Icon property of each Window or Form in the application._

Comment: I have tried this and it still does not work. It throws no errors, instead the taskbar icon stays as the default icon

Comment: @Levi: how did you achive to get a usercontrol to the taskbar? That might lead to your solution

Comment: I did this by calling the [Control.SetTopLevel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.settoplevel(v=vs.110).aspx) method setting the usercontrol to a toplevel window